# En la matriz sólo me imprime el último divisor

Tags: c#, .net

Estoy realizando un programa en consola.

Debo leer un número e imprimir los números divisores de ese numero en una matriz de (3 * 3)

Ejecuto el programa y por ejemplo pongo que deseo los divisores de 100. En una linea los hice imprimir y me los muestra bien.

**Pero cuando paso a que los imprima en una matriz de ( 3 * 3) sólo me imprime el 100 en cada casilla**.

Lo único que me falta es que me imprima cada divisor de 100 en la matriz de resto ya esta todo el código.

```
int numero;
int[,] matriz = new int[3, 3];

Console.WriteLine("DE QUE NUMERO DESEA VER LOS DIVISIBLES");
numero = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine($"LOS DIVISORES DE {numero} SON:\n");


for (int divisor = 1; divisor <= numero; divisor++)
{
    if (numero % divisor == 0)
    {
        Console.Write($" {divisor}, ");


        for (int fila = 0; fila < 3; fila++)
        {
            for (int columna = 0; columna < 3; columna++)
            {
                matriz[fila, columna] = divisor;
            }
        }
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("\n__________________________________");
Console.WriteLine("\nMATRIZ\n");

for (int fila = 0; fila < 3; fila++)
{
    for (int columna = 0; columna < 3; columna++)
    {
        Console.Write($" {matriz[fila, columna]} ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}


//---------//
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: ya tienes una pregunta sobre el tema, la idea es seguir el hilo no crear nuevas basadas en el mismo problema sin siquiera cerrar o darle una resolucion a la anterior

Comment: A ok
Fue porque ya lo hice como me dijo pero ahora solo me imprime el ultimo divisor.